# flutter webview bottomnavigation not loading website pages

Tags: flutter, webview, flutter-bottomnavigation

Im having trouble getting the bottomnavigationbar to load the webview pages
This is still all new to me please advice.

```
    children: <Widget>[
      WebView(initialUrl:"http://app.com/index.php" ),
      WebView(initialUrl:"http://app.com/tools.php" ),
      WebView(initialUrl:"http://app.com/profile.php" ),

    ],
    );
   } ),
   bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavyBar(
    selectedIndex: _currentIndex,
    onItemSelected: (index) {
      setState(() => _currentIndex = index);
      _pageController.jumpToPage(index);
    },
    items: <BottomNavyBarItem>[
      BottomNavyBarItem(
          title: Text('Home'),
          icon: Icon(Icons.home),
      ),

      BottomNavyBarItem(
          title: Text('Tools'),
          icon: Icon(Icons.settings)
      ),
      BottomNavyBarItem(
          title: Text('My account'),
          icon: Icon(Icons.chat_bubble)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't exactly know what _pageController is doing, but I imagine that you could hardcode urls in your onItemSelected method. Here's an example:

```
_onSelectBottomItem(int index) {
    if (index == 0) {
      webView.loadUrl("url1");
    } else if (index == 1) {
      webView.loadUrl("url2");
    } else if (index == 2) {
      webView.loadUrl("url3");
    } 
    setState(() {
      _currentIndex = index;
    });
  }
```

You can call _onSelectBottomItem in the onItemSelected method. Hope this helps.